# OPENMP Speedup in Fortran

Tags: fortran, openmp, scaling

```
              count2=1        count2=10       count2=100         count2=1000
processors  time/speedup,1  time/speedup,10 time/speedup,100    time/speedup,1000
1   1.59    1           3.04    1           8.13    1           50.79   1
2   1.32    1.204545    1.708   1.779859    4.23    1.921986    25.53   1.989424
4   0.966   1.645963    1.095   2.776256    2.26    3.597345    12.79   3.971071
8   0.8     1.9875      0.98    3.102041    1.15    7.069565    6.41    7.923557
12  0.797   1.994981    0.83    3.662651    0.98    8.295918    4.28    11.86682
16  0.85    1.870588    0.88    3.454545    0.86    9.453488    3.22    15.77329
24  0.82    1.939024    0.94    3.234043    0.89    9.134831    2.16    23.51389
30  0.835   1.904192    0.88    3.454545    0.85    9.564706    1.76    28.85795
36  1.015   1.566502    0.85    3.576471    0.83    9.795181    1.47    34.55102


!DEC$ if defined(OMP_test)
!$OMP PARALLEL DO PRIVATE(i,j,k,ii)
!DEC$ endif  
    DO  nc=  1,count
    i=  index(nc,1)                        
    j=  index(nc,2)     
    k=  index(nc,3) 
    DO ii = 1,count2 
    xc(nc) = i+j+k+ii
    yc(nc) = i*j*k+ii
    zc(nc) = i+j+k-ii  
    END DO
    END DO
!DEC$ if defined (OMP_test)       
!$OMP END PARALLEL DO
!DEC$ endif
```

The value of count is 10^6 and count2 is been tested for 1, 10, 100, 1000 on 1 to 36 shared memory cores. I am wondering why the speed up is almost negligible when count2 is 1, 10 or 100(after few cores) and then almost ideal when count is 1000 (till 36 cores). All the applications, which I am writing do not have a lot of computation inside the do loop leading to negligible speedup after 8 cores.

Comment: How many cores do you have available on your machine? What do you mean by `after 8 cores` and `till 36 cores`? I'm a little confused...

Comment: I have 48 cores and I have tested the problem for 1,4,8,12,16,24,30, and 36 cores.

Comment: ii needs to be private, too.

Comment: As @AlexanderVogt asked, are you saying that the speedup is almost negligible when count2 is 1 or 10 _when using more than 8 cores_?  And that it is ideal when count**2** is 100 or 1000 _when using fewer than 36 cores_?

Comment: yes, I will add a plot in few minutes. Actually the speedup is ideal only when the count2 is 1000.

Comment: I am not allowed to add the plot but I have added a table showing cputime as well as the speedup for all the cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is pretty much exactly what I'd expect, and as far as I can tell, so were you:

> All the applications, which I am writing do not have a lot of computation inside the do loop leading to negligible speedup after 8 cores.

Let's take the simplest meaningful model of this computation, as described by [Amdahl's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law), where the total amount of time spent is some constant serial overhead (say, the fork/join) plus work that can be effectively parallelized, which is largely controlled by the `count2` parameter.  So we have some model that looks like

> time(p) = a + b(alpha + count2)/p

or

> cpu_time(p) = p*time(p) = a p + b alpha + b count2

where a is the overhead, b*(alpha + count2) is the amount of parallelizable work inside the loop.

So we can fit that easily enough, and find something like the following:
[image: Linear Amdahl Model]

This fit doesn't do so hot at the largest number of processors, as there's presumably memory contention (and core contention - is that with hyperthreading?) at the largest number of cores, and we've foolishly assumed overhead was constant.  As a result, the serial overhead is overestimated, and the work per count2 is underestimated.  But for the rest of the data it seems to be consistent with the overall trend.

So I'm not sure what you were hoping for here - with small `count2`, you have very little CPU work to do, and so throwing more CPUs at the problem won't speed things up.  Instead, you're memory bandwidth limited, and that's what needs to be worked on to improve performance.

Comment: I agree with  everything you said but the thing which is bothering me is the value of count is 1000000 (1 million). So, there is enough work for processors to do and hence was expecting speedup for lower count2 values.

Comment: @RS_DFI - it doesn't matter if what's inside the loop is memory-bandwidth-limited rather than CPU limited.  It'll mean you can break the count1 loop up into several nice big, independent chunks; but that won't help you if each chunk element is memory-bandwidth constrained, not CPU constrained.  You'll still have a bunch of cores contending for memory - they'll just be duking it out 1M times instead of 1K times.  It would be the same if it were I/O, rather than memory, which was the bottleneck.

Comment: Is the memory-bandwidth constrained due to size of xc,yc,zc arrays?

Comment: Probably the `index` arrays more; you're accessing xc/yc/zc in a cache-friendly order, but not so index (per loop iteration).  But you'd have to profile to really see where you're stalling due to memory.